# Like button on website not feeding likes to FB page

Tags: button, web, facebook-like

I have a FB like button on www.attachmentparentinguk.com showing 31 likes while my FB page shows 5 likes. Button code pasted directly from FB page.

FB page also not showing in search properly.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Theres no problem at all. The likes from the website aren't the same from the FB page. To change this, all you have to do is use the FB page url to the like button, if you want to use the likes from your page instead of the website and vice versa.

About the search, I don't know what and why. Maybe someone else cold help on this.
I've seen that even if you type all the page, the search don't return the page link but if instead you type the name with the UK lowercase, the AJAX suggestions doesn't show, but the search page cames with it in first place as a suggestion.

Just checkout to see if you have no extra spaces (in the begining, end or in between the words) in the profile or page name in FP configuration page.

Comment: Thank you so much. I decided to change the FB logo on the website. Am stumped about the search error. I inadvertently crests a duplicate page when creating that one. I deleted it but maybe until 2 weeks has passed and that's confirmed...do you think I should delete it and start again?

Comment: Maybe it has something about your problem. If you can start over, its the best thing to do, if not, than you can check the data in the infor page for incorrect or invalid characters (even invisible ones that can be copyed like TAB or line breaks)